# Areca palm growth stunted after repotting it in a larger pot since last 6 months

Tags: palm, areca-palm

[image]

I repotted Areca palm in a large pot 6 months ago. During repotting some small roots were damaged. However, since then the growth of my Areca palm has stunted. I applied compost, liquid chemical fertilizer, humic acid and epsom salt. However, nothing seems to be boosting the growth of the plant. The new leaves which started appearing also looks deformed. What should I do?